# Add a server to a running NTP daemon

Tags: linux, debian, ntp, ntpd, debian-bullseye

I’m willing to add my home NTP server to my running NTP daemon whenever I connect to my home VPN.

I’m pretty sure I managed to have this working, several years ago, with a command like

```
ntpdc -c 'keyid 10' -c 'passwd XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' -c 'addserver 192.168.0.1' localhost
```

I tried to re-implement this on a Debian Bullseye system, but that command fails with

```
localhost: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

Note that my `/etc/ntp.conf` contains:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help
…
# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
…
keys /etc/ntp.keys
requestkey 10
```

and my `/etc/ntp.keys` contains:

```
10 MD5 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  # MD5 key
```

FWIW, the XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX password is **not** redacted.

It also is not a firewall issue, since `ntpdc -np localhost` replies correctly.

Any idea what I missed to allow `ntpdc` to add a server? Or how I can have `ntpd` log the reason why it did not reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation, I found out what was missing.

The `/etc/ntp.conf` should contain:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help
…
# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
…
enable mode7
keys /etc/ntp.keys
trustedkey 10
requestkey 10
```

Rationale:

- `ntpdc` is using “private” (also known as mode 7) commands, which are disallowed by default and allowed by the `enable mode7` configuration,
- keys read from the file given by the `keys` configuration are disabled by default and a enabled by the `trustedkey` configuration.